# jQuery AJAX-request loading twice

Tags: jquery

I'm building an infinite Scroll which fetches results from a database when the scroller hits the bottom of the page. It's all working fine except for one small thing; it is fetching the results twice if I scroll down fast, as if the function is executed twice.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        var ID = $('.stbody:last').attr('id').match(/stbody(\d+)/)[1];
        $('#loader').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax_loadmore.php?lCom=" + ID,
            success: function (result) {
                if(result) {
                    $('#moreComments').append(result);
                    $('#loader').hide();
                } else {
                    $('#loader').hide();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Javascript is _somewhat_ single threaded; have you tried simply marking a flag to indicate an ajax request for content has been invoked and thus to simply exit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an addition to @JamWaffles answer:

You may just exit the function with `return;` instead of calling `request.abort();`. Otherwise you will make two AJAX requests for the same data = unnecessary load for your server. You should then, however, reset the request object with `request = null;` in the success and error callback.

PS. Would post this as a comment, but I can't.

Answer (score 4):

Your AJAX requests are most likely queueing up behind one another, because they are *asynchronous*, even though JavaScript itself is mostly single threaded.

You can use the `abort()` method to make sure only one request runs at a time. You need to assign the jqXHR object returned by `$.ajax()` to a variable:

```
var request;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        var ID = $('.stbody:last').attr('id').match(/stbody(\d+)/)[1];
        $('#loader').show();

        // Abort any currently executing request
        if(request) {
            request.abort();
        }

        // Make a new request
        request = $.ajax({
            url: "ajax_loadmore.php?lCom=" + ID,
            success: function (result) {
                if(result) {
                    $('#moreComments').append(result);
                    $('#loader').hide();
                } else {
                    $('#loader').hide();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

`abort()` is a native function of the [XMLHttpRequest object](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/), however it is exposed by jQuery's jqXHR object, so can be called as usual.

Comment: Thnx! This helped. I did combine it with the answer below to get a faster result though. I do have another problem now and that is that it a'int working in Firefox for some reason.. It works in IE 9, Chrome and Safari.. any known jquery-problems with firefox?

Comment: Have you checked FF's debug console for errors (or Firebug's if you have it installed)?