# Load Ajax data while page scrolls down using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

To load the data when page scrolls down using function like this

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
        {
            //alert('Scrolling Down');
            get_summary_details(); //Here it calls AJax Function load the data

        }
    });
```

`get_summary_details()` function works fine when page scrolls down.This function is like this

```
function get_summary_details()
    {

        var dataString=[];
        $('div.company_summary_data').each(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            dataString.push(id);
        });                     
        $.ajax({
            url:"getajaxcompanysummarydetails",
            type:"POST",
            //dataType: "json",
            data:"last_app_data_id="+JSON.stringify(dataString),
            success:function(data)
            {                               
                $('.company_summary_data:last').after(data);

            }

        });         
    }
```

My problem is

- while `get_summary_details()` processing the Request user will go to `top` of the page and `Scroll` down , again this `get_summary_details()` function will execute.

How to prevent that Second Request Processing without completion of first Request.Is this Possible? Because of this i am getting duplicate records of data.I need to prevent to display duplicate records.

Thanks!

Comment: What about using `Boolean` flag to check whether the request is in process or not?

Comment: Sorry i didnt get you. Could you explain briefly..@Regent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether the ajax request is busy by setting a boolean flag

```
var loadingSummaryDetails = false;
```

Set it to true when you start the Ajax and to false when the call finishes

```
function get_summary_details()
{
    if(loadingSummaryDetails) {
        return;
    }
    loadingSummaryDetails = true;

    var dataString=[];
    $('div.company_summary_data').each(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        dataString.push(id);
    });                     
    $.ajax({
        url:"getajaxcompanysummarydetails",
        type:"POST",
        //dataType: "json",
        data:"last_app_data_id="+JSON.stringify(dataString),
        success:function(data)
        {     
            $('.company_summary_data:last').after(data);

        }

    }).always(function()
        {     
            loadingSummaryDetails = false;
        });         
}
```

Comment: @user3454479 `loadingSummaryDetails` is `Boolean` flag that I was talking about.

Comment: @Regent I changed it to use the always method now

Answer (score 2):

Your AJAX requests are most likely queueing up behind one another, because they are asynchronous, even though JavaScript itself is mostly single threaded.

You can use the `abort()` method to make sure only one request runs at a time. You need to assign the jqXHR object returned by `$.ajax()` to a variable:

please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415026/jquery-ajax-request-loading-twice)